# Two different buttons to show and hide an area in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 on my site and I have plenty of spots where I use buttons/links to toggle areas' visibility using the `data-toggle="collapse"` technique with bootstrap CSS.

However I have one area where I want two buttons, a Show and a Hide button. One of which will show the relevant DIV, the other to hide it.

I know I can also do this with jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()`, but is there a simple Bootstrap "syntax" for this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this functionality with just a few lines of code.

Copy this into the js somewhere,,

```
$("[data-hide]").click(function(){
    $($(this).attr('data-hide')).hide();
});

$("[data-show]").click(function(){
    $($(this).attr('data-show')).show();
});
```

now all you have to do is add `data-hide='#id_of_element_to_hide'` or `data-show='.classname_of_elements_to_show'` to show or hide your content.

Here's a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/yrh0kusL/

Comment: You can use `.collapse('hide')` instead of `.hide()` and `.collapse('show')` instead of `.show()` to get the default animation.